# Example of element of double dual that is not an evaluation map

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, dual-spaces

It's well known that if $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, then there is a natural injection from $V$ to the double dual $V^{**}$, which associates to every $v \in V$ the evaluation map $\phi \mapsto \phi(v)$, where $\phi: V \to F$ is an arbitrary functional in $V^*$. It's also well known that this injection is an isomorphism if $V$ is finite-dimensional, as any finite-dimensional vector space has the same dimension as its dual.

My question is this: are there any nice, readily understood examples of *infinite*-dimensional vector spaces $V$ for which an element of $V^{**}$ that is not an evaluation map can be explicitly constructed (at least with the axiom of choice)? I find infinite-dimensional double dual spaces hard even to think about.

Comment: Do you want to consider the *algebraic* dual or the *continuous* dual of $V$?  To put it another way, do we have any notion of topology/continuity over this vector space?

Comment: I think you need some form of choice for this. If you consider $\mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})}$ (countable dimension), then its dual is $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the space of all sequences. The subspace of convergent sequences admits an obvious linear form that, with choice, can be extended to the whole of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Such linear form is not an evaluation map.

Comment: I would suspect that it is impossible to give any example without using the axiom of choice (and therefore impossible to give any truly explicit example).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I had the algebraic dual in mind.

Comment: @ConnorHarris I suspected as much and answered accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick example, using the axiom of choice: take $V$ to be the set of polynomials with real coefficients. Let $S$ denote the subspace of $V^*$ consisting of those functionals such that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x^n)$ exists.  With the axiom of choice, there necessarily exists a complementary subspace $S'$ such that $V = S \oplus S'$.

Define $\phi:S \to \Bbb R$ by $\phi(f) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x^n)$.  Define $\phi:S' \to \Bbb R$ by $\phi(f) = 0$.  Extend $\phi$ to all of $V$ by linearity.

Comment: In the second line, should there be something after $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x^n)$? Possibly just that the limit exists?

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Whoops, never mind! Fixed it.

Comment: @Ben Grossmann, I guess you mean $V^*=S\oplus S'$. Anyhow, is it possible to prove that such a functional you built cannot be represented as an evaluation map? I am ready for a thumb up if this is the case :).