# Why do we need the evaluation map for defining a function in the double dual?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm currently studying a lot about duals and double duals. My question is related to the latter.

I noticed that whenever one talks about double duals, one first defines an *evaluation map*. But I don't quite understand the motivation for introducing this concept, and here is why.

Suppose $V^{\star\star}$ is the double dual of the vector space $V$. I understand that $V^{\star\star}$ is the collection of all linear functions $\varphi : V^{\prime} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. Thus, $\varphi$ maps linear functionals to scalars; symbolically, I guess it would look something like $\varphi(\psi) = \varphi\psi \in \mathbb{F}$.

Why, then, do we need to introduce the evaluation map to further "spell-out" what $\varphi(\psi)$ means?

Thank you

Comment: Well, how do you know the map from $V^{**}$ to $V$ exists?

Comment: @DonThousand Are you saying that to ensure the existence of such a map, we need to construct one, namely, the evaluation function?

Comment: Well, sending a linear functional $\psi \in V'$ to a specific value $\psi(v) \in \mathbb F$ is the most natural thing that comes to mind when defining a functional in $V''$. Of course, not every functional in $V''$ is of this form, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471015/example-of-element-of-double-dual-that-is-not-an-evaluation-map) for example.